# Get all values from form

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

I have this form and i want to save all inputs from textarea in a list in my Controller. How can I do this?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <h6 for="exampleFormControlTextarea3" class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)</h6>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea3" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `name="textarea3"` to textarea

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h6 for="exampleFormControlTextarea3" class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text)</h6>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="textarea3" id="exampleFormControlTextarea3" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            }
```

In controller:

```
string texts = Request["textarea3"]; // it will be a,b,c if you input to 3 textarea a and b and c

string[] arr = texts.Split(new[] {','}); //hande each textarea
```

Comment: With Request["textarea"] i get "cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type http request"; i changed with Request.Form["textarea3"] and it worked.. Thank you soo much !!